# Rollup Vue 3 Dynamic img src

Tags: vue.js, rollup

Dynamic img src were handled by Webpack's require:

```html
<img :src="require(`@/assets/${posts.img}`)" alt="">
```

How to do this on a vite-app that uses Rollup?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to [docs](https://github.com/originjs/webpack-to-vite/blob/80bec912e3a4033f3ec697695236544859fdc583/README.md?plain=1#L212-L265) of [webpack-to-vite](https://github.com/originjs/webpack-to-vite)：

use Vite's API `import.meta.glob` to convert dynamic require(e.g. `require('@assets/images/' + options.src)`), you can refer to the following steps

1. create a Model to save the imported modules, use async methods to dynamically import the modules and update them to the Model

```js
// src/store/index.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
const assets = import.meta.glob('../assets/**')
Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    assets: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    setAssets(state, data) {
      state.assets = Object.assign({}, state.assets, data)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async getAssets({ commit }, url) {
      const getAsset = assets[url]
      if (!getAsset) {
        commit('setAssets', { [url]: ''})
      } else {
        const asset = await getAsset()
        commit('setAssets', { [url]: asset.default })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

2. use in `.vue` SFC

```js
// img1.vue
<template>
  <img :src="$store.state.assets['../assets/images/' + options.src]" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "img1",
  props: {
    options: Object
  },
  watch: {
    'options.src': {
      handler (val) {
        this.$store.dispatch('getAssets', `../assets/images/${val}`)
      },
      immediate: true,
      deep: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```